# Django Tutoril 4,after amend views.py the detail site missing the vote action?

Tags: python, django

Recently I started learning Django, and early on I ran into a problem:
in part 4 of this tutorial, after I modify my code to generic views, the detail site looks like a different page than it was before.

I cannot find the point, and it didn't show me an error statement.

I've posted the code below.

**polls/urls.py:**

```
from polls.models import Poll

urlpatterns =patterns('',
    url(r'$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
            context_object_name='latest_poll_list',
            template_name='polls/index.html'),
        name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=Poll,
            template_name='polls/detail.html'),
        name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=Poll,
            template_name='polls/results.html'),
        name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'polls.views.vote', name='vote'),
    )
```

**index.html**

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a  href = "{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{poll.question}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
        <p> No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**detail.html**

```
<h1>{{poll.question}}</h1>

{%if error_message %}<p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>{%endif%}

<form action = '{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}' method = 'post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type = 'radio' name = 'choice' id = 'choice{{forloop.counter}}' value = '{{choice.id}}'/>
    <lable for = 'choice{{forloop.counter}}'>{{choice.choice_text}}</lable><br/>
    {%endfor%}
<input type ='submit' value = 'Vote'/>
</form>
```

Comment: it is really strange for me ,and i am absulotely beginner..

Comment: if i didn't describe the quesion clearly,please just tell me ...

Comment: @zds_cn Without knowing exactly what the difference was for you, can you verify that all the views are pointing towards the proper pages? It's possible that you were seeing the incorrect page before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**polls/urls.py**

Your regex match for the first url should be `r'^$'`.

```
urlpatterns =patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(....
```